# Summing only particular rows in Excel with correspondence to a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

[image]

Is there any way to sum values from '**units sold**' column only for values that correspond to a particular '**flavour**' in the other column (in this case, I labeled one such case in yellow)? I was thinking of using the COUNTIF function, but in order for that to work, I'd need another argument.

Is there any other function that I may use for this purpose?

Comment: try: =SUMPRODUCT(B2:B200*--(C2:C200="chocolate"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUMIFS()` function like-

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B200,C2:C200,"chocolate")
```

Comment: Or `=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"chocolate")` for full column.